# Is there a more effective way of parsing a file into an array?

Tags: c

I want to put a file into an array. Is there a more effective way of doing this? I'm using fgetc to get individual character of a text file. Here is what I have so far.

```
while((temp_airports[i] = fgetc(airports)) != EOF) {
      c=temp_airports[i];
      printf("%c",temp_airports[i]);
      i++;
    }
```

Is there a more effective or straight forward way of putting contents of a text file into an array? I think fgets would work but I don't know the size of the file.

Comment: without knowing the format of the file it's difficult to give a precise answer but just general ones..

Comment: What do you mean by format of file? Can you take a look at this file and help me determain the format? http://ece.umd.edu/class/enee150.S2012/assignments/pr2/airports.txt

Comment: Your question isn't entirely clear. Do you want an array of chars (like in your example), or actually an array of strings, with one line per string?

Comment: I would like an array of strings per line. The text file has a `\n` at the end of every line. Is there a way I can separate the line?

Answer (score 4):

Use the [`fread`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/fread/) function to a char buffer from the file at once

Answer (score 1):

First you need to know the file size, NilObject's code for this:

```
#include <sys/stat.h>

off_t fsize(const char *filename) {
    struct stat st; 

    if (stat(filename, &st) == 0)
        return st.st_size;

    return -1; 
}
```

Then allocate a buffer with that size and perform an fread.

Answer (score 0):

As a general answer you can use the [`fscanf`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/fscanf/) that will provide basic parsing abilities if file in in ASCII.

Comment: What has ASCII to do with anything?

Comment: If file is not ASCII but just binary plain data then you would just `fread` whole structures or integral types without bothering with parsing.

Comment: What about EBCDIC?  Everyone forgets about poor old EBCDIC.

Comment: @CarlNorum And rightly so. With the gaps in the alphabet... tsk tsk.

Comment: Indeed.  I just wanted to support @KerrekSB - encoding can make a big difference.